# Reading environment variables in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a script that tries to read from the arc environment using

```
import arcpy
tolerance = arcpy.env.XYTolerance
```

as recommended here:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000w000000

Alas `tolerance` always ends up as `None`.  Even when I set it explicity in the `Environments...` part of the script dialog box.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I have loaded up arcmap and using the built in python interpreter I ran through the commands outlined in the helpfiles you linked. It seems that the syntax is very precise, but I was able to set the tolerance and then retrieve it as a variable called `tolerance` using the following steps:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> from arcpy import env
>>> env.workspace = 'C:\\shapefiles\\final'
>>> env.XYTolerance = 2.5
>>> tolerance = env.XYTolerance
>>> print tolerance
2.5 Unknown
>>>
```

Comment: Ok... but how to retrieve `XYTolerance` from the script dialog box?  Which workspace does that live in?